# Is [nested] tag a meta tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

This tag is pretty much a meta tag. Just from the question list, we see all sort of things that can be [nested](/questions/tagged/nested):

> [Nesting JQuery UI tabs in custom JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11234423/nesting-jquery-ui-tabs-in-custom-jquery)
>   [C++ Nested class is producing undefined references to outer class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246171/c-nested-class-is-producing-undefined-references-to-outer-class)
>   [Nested and independent GIT repos, for Backup, how?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11269804/nested-and-independent-git-repos-for-backup-how)
>   [PHP - Nested Looping Trouble](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194997/php-nested-looping-trouble)

A search on "nested" brings up quite a number of more specific "nested-XXX" tags that can be applied to many questions tagged [nested](/questions/tagged/nested).

Should this tag stay at all?

If it stays, then I think a good wiki should be written for it, so that people know to use other tags over this tag.

Comment: It's not a *pure* meta tag, but it certainly does mean more than one thing depending on the context, which makes it a *bad* tag at the minimum.  I'm not sure if it can be safely removed though...